# What is Microsoft.MvcValidation used for in ASP.NET MVC 3 projects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and don't understand the purpose of all the JavaScript files that are added to the project by default.

What's the purpose of MicrosoftMvcValidation.js?  Whatever it's used for, can it be swapped out for a jquery-based implementation?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MicrosoftMvcValidation.js will be used if you decide that you do not want to use the new unobtrusive jQuery validation on the client side.

You can make this choice for you entire applicastion in the web.config file here:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
  </appSettings>
```

So in the above example the jQuery validation will be used.